# Proper way to access WebElement in Selenium Which have the same name or id in java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm having a problem with the above question... But first if there is an answer for this question within this site that I miss then in advance I apologize for making a duplicate question...

My problem is when I have a loop in php that creates a duplicate for example a button, which also creates the same name and id for this element that I need to access and Yes I can access this element though just the first instance that the findbyid method in selenium webdriver gives.

I have a sloppy fix for it by creating a multiple command that sends a tab key that I have to specify first how many iterations I have execute adding a tab key before performing the action.

Is there any way that I can access this element via a certain index or special location..
lastly sorry for my English being unreadable please bear with me on that.. and thanks in advance...

Comment: If possible include what you have already done within the question, this will help people to answer appropriately

Comment: Yes I will try to post my recent work first thing tomorrow.. I had left my work at the office. tnx for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form a list of the webelements and then access the webelement within that list by its index.

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.id("id"));
buttons[0].click();
buttons[1].click();
buttons[n].click();
```

Obviously, you'd need to know which position within the list to access but from what I can see you already know this due to your tabbing attempt.

Comment: Wow hehe I never expect to implement it that way but I like the answer I hope it answer my problem a really clear way of coding tnx I'll give a  feed back as soon as I tried it.. tnx Mark!

Comment: Hi Mark i tried this approach but it need to cast the driver.finElements(By.id("id")); to List<WebElement> if I do it gives me an org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List error

Comment: Edited Sorry my mistake its findELements not just one elements hehe tnx I Think I can work with this... Sorry again I can't vote you up since I yet don't have the perks to, but I'll remember your name as a alternative tnx...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way, @MarkRowlands said, or if you know the index, you can do:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='id'])[n]")) //n - your index
```

But I don't recommend you to use indexes. In my practice there's always locator for the exact element

Comment: Up-vote for Alex's answer. you "can" use indexing but personally, I really wouldn't.

Comment: in practice some say avoid the use of xpath as much as possible? but I'll try this answer too.. tnx Alexander!

Comment: can you explain to me good sir to use locators better.. I don't have much flexibility for its not my system that I'm debugging but other systems I have to be content with that and it really give me problems..